# Unable to inject service angular2-rc4

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-services

I'm having one UserService which contains some static methods as below:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class UserInfoService {
    private static _userInfo: any;

    static put(userInfo:any) {
        this._userInfo = userInfo;   
    }
    static getRole() : string {
        if (this._userInfo) {
            return this._userInfo.role;
        }
        return '';
    }
    static getUserInfo() : string {
        return this._userInfo;
    }
}
```

I'm injecting it in boot.ts as shown below:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [  UserInfoService])
```

I'm using this service in another component as below:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {UserInfoService} from "../service/user.info";

@Component({
    selector: 'nav-bar',
    templateUrl: 'template/navbar.html'
});
export class NavigationComponent {
     constructor() {
        this.userInfo = UserInfoService.getUserInfo();
     }
}
```

This NavigationComponent calls is not able to access UserInfoService.
Note: This was working with angular2-rc1. I'm facing this issue after upgrading to rc4.
Please help.

Comment: you have inject `UserInfoService` inside `constructor` to get its instance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see what you're trying to accomplish by injecting a service which only has static methods and variables.

I'd suggest using the service like a singleton instead, so that injecting it actually makes some sense:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class UserInfoService {
    private _userInfo: any;

     put(userInfo:any) {
        this._userInfo = userInfo;   
    }
    getRole() : string {
        if (this._userInfo) {
            return this._userInfo.role;
        }
        return '';
    }
    getUserInfo() : string {
        return this._userInfo;
    }
}
```

And in your component:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {UserInfoService} from "../service/user.info";

@Component({
    selector: 'nav-bar',
    templateUrl: 'template/navbar.html'
});
export class NavigationComponent {
     userInfo: string;

     constructor(private _userInfoService: UserInfoService) {
        this.userInfo = _userInfoService.getUserInfo();
     }
}
```

Comment: I used static methods so that I dont have to create instance in constructor and it was working till rc1. But looks like something has got changed with rc4 which is interrupting this from working. Anyway, I'll create instance in constructor and use it.. Thanks

Comment: If it's completely static, you won't need to inject it.

Comment: That means I dont need to use @Injectable and I dont need to give in bootstrap('appComponent',[]) ??

Comment: That's right. If methods are static, you can access them, without instantiating the class, so you don't need to inject it anywhere.

Comment: Then why it was not working in my code "UserInfoService.getUserInfo()". I dont think just adding @Injectable annotation can stop me from accessing its stating method.

Answer (score 2):

just make a instance of your service if you want to use it in any of your component ....

In your constructor make userinfoservice instance as:

```
constructor(private userInfoService:UserInfoService) {

   //......now you can use your functions by 
   userInfoService.getUserInfo()
}
```

that's it ,it works fine with it :)